# Passing a model to a different controller from a view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Registration">Register</button>
```

Its on a sign-in page that has this link which goes to a registration page. I'd like to preserve the username and password entered on this page when the user clicks the link to go to the registration page, so is there a way to pass it a new model such that the user goes to the registration page and already has their ID and password entered?

For example, I am trying to do something like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Registration", new RegistrationModel { ID = Model.ID, Password = Model.Password })'">Register</button>
```

Comment: You have 2 fields and 2 buttons with different actions right?

Comment: Why isn't the registration in a `form`? The values would then be automatically sent to the controller. Where does the user fill their _username_  and _password_?

Comment: Razor code is parsed on the server before its sent to the view so `...new RegistrationModel { ID = Model.ID....` would only return the initial model values, not what was edited. You need javascript/jquery to update the `href` attribute based on user entered data. But id you seriously thinking of passing a password in a url then you need to rethink what your doing

Comment: @StephenMuecke SSL encrypts URLs, but I'm pretty new to MVC so...I was wondering what the best practice is of preserving some sort of a state between different views.

Comment: Wrap the `input`s and the `button` in a `form` and submit it to the server. Your action would then receive as a parameter an object containing exactly what you want.

Comment: @AndreiV I have a sign-in page, where the user can specify their username and password, but I also have this Register button, which, when clicked, I would like it to pass that username and password to a different controller that does registrations. That other controller has its own model and view. It does have a submit button on it, but the problem is how to preserve that username and password when the user hits the Register button between two different views with two different models?

Comment: @StephenMuecke But you're right, thinking about it some more, it would be terrible to see the password as plaintext in a URL. So there must be a better way of doing this...but how? I need to pass this and make it invisible to the user...

Comment: @Alexandru, Your work flow is unclear. Why would a user who is not registered fill out a values in a login form. Just include a link to the register form where they can fill out the details and as a result be logged in.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I know but, its a convenience thing that is nice to have. Surely there must be a way to do this? For example, they try to log in, and realize that the login failed. Whoops, they never created this account, they hit register. Why fill out the username and password again? But I'd like to focus on solving this problem to be honest, and not get into a debate on the design itself.

Comment: You could have a hidden `form`. When clicking on the _Register_ button, you'd copy the data from the _Sign In_ `form` and securely post it to whatever controller action you want, with the corresponding model property names.

Comment: @AndreiV Do you happen to have a link to something similar so I can see how others have done this?

Comment: @Alexandru, Not ever seen anything like that before. You could do something like SO where you include both forms (initially hidden) and 2 'links/buttons' for login and register which show the corresponding form and post to their respective controllers

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any sample project. It was just a quick thought of what I would have tried.

Comment: You simply want to submit the form to a different controller even though your view only has one view model associated with it.  When it comes to submitting a form, MVC doesn't care what the view model is that is associated with the view, all it wants to know is that the names being submitted match up.  So if both models have a `Username` and `Password` property, it doesn't matter which controller/action you submit it to, it will bind just fine.

Comment: @Coulton, The potential issue with that is that `Login` model and `Register` model will contain different properties, for example a `Register` model typically has an additional property for `ConfirmPassword`

Comment: It's not a problem if you make your Register request model fit the intended purpose in terms of properties and validation.

Comment: Guys, I guess I could also pass it within TempData...

Comment: There really isn't any need to use tempdata, posting the values is fine

Comment: Hopefully the answer that I have submitted answers the question sufficiently.  Post to two different forms controlled by Javascript and a check on a bool for your specific use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is just post your values to which ever controller you want to handle it and share the same textbox names.

Say you have a view like so, containing your form:

```
@model LoginFormViewModel

@* Form element defaults to posting to Login controller, but has an attribute containing the URL to the Registration controller should we need it *@
<form id="login_form" method="post" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Login")" data-registration-url="@Url.Action("Index", "Registration")">

    @* Username field *@
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username)

    @* Password field *@
    @Html.PasswordFor(x => x.Password, new { value = Model.Password })

    @* Hidden value that we can check in the controller *@
    <input type="hidden" name="FromLoginPage" value="true" />

    <input type="submit" value="Register" id="register_submit" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

I would use jQuery to control the submitting of the forms:

```
// User clicked regstration button, not login button
$(document).delegate('input#register_submit', 'click', function(e) {

    // Prevent default submitting of the form to the login controller
    e.preventDefault();

    // Get registration URL from the attribute
    var registerActionUrl = $('form#login_form').attr('data-registration-url');

    // Submit the form to the registration controller
    $('form#login_form').attr('action', registerActionUrl).submit();
});
```

Here's the model `LoginViewModel` and `RegistrationViewModel` that share properties with the same names (`Username` and `Password`), this will come in handy for binding up depending on which controller we submit the form to:

```
// Login model
public LoginViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

// Registration view model    
public RegistrationViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool FromLoginPage { get; set; }

    // ... other fields that won't get bound when submitted from login page
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

In the Login controller we handle things normally, but within the registration form we can do a quick check on `FromLoginPage` submitted from the login page to return the registration page back to the user with the fields populated:

```
// Login controller
[HttpPost]
public LoginController : Controller
{
    public Index(LoginViewModel requestmodel)
    {
        // Validate login
        // Process login

        // Return the view
        return View(requestmodel);
    }
}

// Registration controller
[HttpPost]
public RegistrationController : Controller
{
    public Index(RegistrationViewModel requestModel)
    {
        // Submitted from the login page?
        if (requestModel.FromLoginPage)
        {
            // Clear any model validation errors so far
            this.ModelState.Clear();

            // Just load the registration page with the values populated
           return View(requestmodel);
        }

        // A normal registration request from registration page, perform validation on entire model

        // Process login here
        return View(requestmodel);
    }
}
```

Comment: This technique is great. The only issue I have with it is that it will post to the registration page which will run some validation, so I suppose you may be able to bypass this by having a different post method/action on the registration page that clears the ModelState and posting to that instead. Thanks for the great answer by the way!

Comment: Great to hear.  I have added in a ModelState.Clear() before returning the view back, does that solve the issue?

Comment: I haven't tested it, but I'm sure it would!

Comment: Good luck, let me know if any other issues with it